Issues with Covington keys
I'm having an issue getting certain keys in the covington package to work. Specifically, I'd like to include a preamble and a postamble in an example. I've copied some text below from the manual, and I'm not able to compile it. I get errors like:
Package xkeyval Error: postamble' undefined in families cov@subex'.
Am I missing something or is the package not working?
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{covington}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
Dies ein ungrammatischem Satz ist.
\end{example}

\begin{example}[preamble={test}]
Dies ein ungrammatischem Satz ist.
\end{example}

\begin{subexamples}[preamble={Here are two sentences},
postamble={(Doe 1974: 12)}]
\item This is the first sentence.
\item This is the second sentence.
\end{subexamples}

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SX! I can reproduce the error when I use TeX Live 2022 on Overleaf. With TeX Live 2023 on Overleaf, however, the above code compiles just fine. I therefore suggest that you update your TeX installation.

Also no problem with the MiKTeX Distribution on Windows, updated earlier today.

That fixed it - thank you!
